# Issue with rolling 6 month filter in pyspark

Tags: sql, pyspark

I'm trying to write a SQL query in pyspark that will output the past rolling 6 months as one of the columns. I was able to successfully do this with the code below, but apparently there's a way to do this without a where clause (potentially a case statement) that I'm expected to replicate instead, but I'm stuck.  Any help is appreciated.

```
Select 
      to_date(calendar_dt)
from  calendar
where calendar_dt >= DATEADD(month, -6, current_date) 
  and calendar_dt < DATEADD(month, 0, current_date)
```

Comment: This is the only way if you need to fetch data from last 6 month. unless you want to calculate something for all the data based on rolling 6 month that's another thing which you can use window functions. maybe provide more information as well as sample data and desired output so we can give more clear answer.